# изменение input src js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function dawn(input)
    {
    input.value =   input.value != 'close' ?  'close' : 'open' 
    }
 $(function(){
  $("#closeinput").click(function () {
      $("#closediv").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='closediv'>
  <b>Правило.</b> Ё должна использоваться: в случаях возможных разночтений; в словарях; в книгах для изучающих русский язык (т. е. детей и иностранцев); для правильного прочтения редких топонимов, названий или фамилий. Во всех остальных случаях наличие
  буквы ё только затрудняет чтение. Она плохо выглядит, зато хорошо звучит.
</div>
<input type="button" id='closeinput' value="close" onclick="dawn(this)">
```

Мне нужно вместо кнопки open/close была картинка которая имзеняеться тоесть например стрелочка вниз вместо кнопки open (open.png) и стрелочка вверх вместо close (close.png)
ВАЖНО! Изначально блок должен быть ОТКРЫТЫМ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function dawn(input) {

}
$(function() {
  $("#closeinput").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_48px-512.png");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("open");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png");
    }
    $("#closediv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='closediv'>
  <b>Правило.</b> Ё должна использоваться: в случаях возможных разночтений; в словарях; в книгах для изучающих русский язык (т. е. детей и иностранцев); для правильного прочтения редких топонимов, названий или фамилий. Во всех остальных случаях наличие
  буквы ё только затрудняет чтение. Она плохо выглядит, зато хорошо звучит.
</div>
<button id='closeinput' onclick="dawn(this)" class="open">
  <img id='closeimg' src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" style="width:30px">
</button>
```